# Select the option based on the value passed in

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select the dropdown menu to the certain option when I click a button

I have

Html

```
   <select id='selectmenu'>
    <option>
    1
    </option>
    <option>
    2
    </option>
    <option>
    3
    </option>   

    </select>

    <a id='click'>click</a>
```

Jquery

```
  $('#click').click(function(){

      var option=3;
      //I want the select dropdown menu to select option 3 when I click the button. 
      //$('#selectmenu').select()  //I think it will be something like this....

    })
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#selectmenu').val(3); //p00f!
```

Comment: well. this is not what I was asking in my question. I need to select the option based on the option html (in my case 3). val(3) is based on the option value, not option texts. +1 for the help though

Comment: @FlyingCat you did not set values, therefore the value defaults to the text inside of the option element